# How to check if Thread finished execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-state

I have following problem:

I want to check (C#) if a thread has finished execution, i.e. if the thread method has returned. What I do now is call `Thread.Join(1)`, but this gives a 1 ms delay. Is there any way to simply check if a thread has finished. Inspecting `Thread.ThreadState` just seems too cumbersome.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the [`Thread.IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) flag. This is to give the thread status.

Answer (score 16):

For a thread you have the `myThread.IsAlive` property. It is false if the thread method returned or the thread was aborted.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to block the current thread by waiting/checking for the other running thread completion, you can
implement callback method like this.

```
Action onCompleted = () => 
{  
    //On complete action
};

var thread = new Thread(
  () =>
  {
    try
    {
      // Do your work
    }
    finally
    {
      onCompleted();
    }
  });
thread.Start();
```

If you are dealing with controls that doesn't support cross-thread operation, then you have to invoke the callback method

```
this.Invoke(onCompleted);
```

Comment: Can you pass id back to the onCompleted()  callback?

Comment: @Mike Yes. Add a parameter to the onCompleted action and pass the parameter when it is invoked.

Answer (score 11):

You could fire an event from your thread when it finishes and subscribe to that.

Alternatively you can call [`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) without any arguments:

> Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping.

[`Thread.Join(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b1kkss0.aspx) will:

> Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates or the specified time elapses, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping.

In this case the specified time is 1 millisecond.

Comment: Before calling Thread.Join(), you should always check that the current thread is different than the one you are joining. Otherwise you'll never return.

Comment: @DanielRose Can you give a quick snippet on how to check if they are different? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanR Assuming `t1` is the thread you want to join: `if (Thread.CurrentThread != t1) t1.Join();`

Answer (score 10):

Use `Thread.Join(TimeSpan.Zero)`  It will not block the caller and returns a value indicating whether the thread has completed its work. By the way, that is the standard way of testing all `WaitHandle` classes as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use IsAlive extensively, unless I want to block the current execution (of the calling thread), in which case I just call Join() without a parameter.  Now, be aware that IsAlive may return false if the target thread has not actually started execution yet for any reason.

Carlos Merighe.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to use it. Using a Join is one way. Another way of doing it is let the thread notify the caller of the thread by using an event. For instance when you have your graphical user interface (GUI) thread that calls a process which runs for a while and needs to update the GUI when it finishes, you can use the event to do this. This website gives you an idea about how to work with events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx

Remember that it will result in cross-threading operations and in case you want to update the GUI from another thread, you will have to use the `Invoke` method of the control which you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), with the [OnRunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx) you can do it.

Comment: Link only answers are bad answers because if the link ever changes your answer becomes useless. Please incorporate the relevant information in the answer and explain why what you are suggesting answers the question.