# this is not waiting form, but completion notification of thread is required

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

```
  private void  btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    Button obj=(Button)sender;
    obj.Content="Cancel";

    SendImage send = new SendImage();
    Thread t = new Thread(send.Image);
    t.Start();
                            //run separate thread.(very long, 9 hours)
                            //so dont wait.

    //but the button should be reset to obj.Content="Send"
    //Can I do this?

    }
```

I want the button to be reset to "Send" (after completion of thread). But form should not wait. Is this possible?

Comment: Wow, 9 hours. 

See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773479/how-to-check-if-thread-finished-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more elegantly using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

XAML for the Button:

```
   <Button x:Name="btnGo" Content="Send" Click="btnGo_Click"></Button>
```

Code :

```
 private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
      _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
      _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object completedSender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs completedArgs)
      {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          btnGo.Content = "Send";
        }));
      };

      _worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
      {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
          btnGo.Content = "Cancel";
        }));

        SendImage sendImage = args.Argument as SendImage;
        if (sendImage == null) return;

        var count = 0;
        while (!_worker.CancellationPending)
        {
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
          {
            btnGo.Content = string.Format("Cancel {0} {1}", sendImage.Name, count);
          }));
          Thread.Sleep(100);
          count++;
        }
      };

      if (_worker.IsBusy)
      {
        _worker.CancelAsync();
      }
      else
      {
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync(new SendImage() { Name = "Test" });
      }

    }
```

Comment: thanks allot for detailed reply. But How '**send.Image**' will be called here?

Comment: You can pass arguments with the RunWorkerAsync() method call. I have updated the sample on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Make the Button a member of your Window/UserControl class (by giving it a `Name` in XAML). When the thread eventually finishes, do this before returning from the thread method:

```
myButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)(() => myButton.Content = "Send"));
```