# I want to show execution time of my program after all threads finish execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, execution-time

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_students; i++)
    {
        new Thread(interview).Start(i);
        n++;              
    } 
    //I want to show execution time after all threads finish execution
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time is {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: You probably need the [`Thread.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join) method. *Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates.* You need to store all threads in an array, and then loop and `Join` the current thread with each one of them.

Comment: @mjwills the question referred as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773479/how-to-check-if-thread-finished-execution) is a quite different question. "Check" and "wait" is not the same thing. A better match is probably this: [How to wait for thread to finish with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net)

Comment: I don't disagree @TheodorZoulias - but the _answers_ in the duplicate were definitely applicable to the OP. Were there better ones? Surely. Heaps of them - if only they'd searched. :)